# How to render angular code of ng-content to component side?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2

How can I use like below : 
Here `{{x-value}}` in content of `<test>` refers to JS class of `test.html`.
How to make it refer to component class.

**test.html**

```html
<test x-value="abc">
<b>{{x-value}}</b>
</test>
```

**test-com.js**

```
@Component({
    selector : 'test',
  template : '<ng-content></ng-content>',
  directives : [IONIC_DIRECTIVES],
  providers : [],
  inputs : ['value : x-value'],
});
export class Test{
   constructor() {

   }
   ...

}
```

Comment: whats the problem with this approach?

Comment: <test x-value="abc">
<b>{{x-value}}</b>               // Here   x-value doesnt print abc (i want to print         abc here
</test>

Comment: But `x-value` refers to input property for `testcmp`. So it will be available in `testcmp` template.

Comment: yes. That is problem. When i put ng-content in template of component then the content of ng-content must refers to testcmp input property. Is there any other way to do this? Please give some hints!!! thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact your expression is executed against the current component. I mean the component where you use the test one.

You could try this if you want to get value from the test component instead:

```
<test #test x-value="abc">
  <b>{{test['x-value']}}</b>
</test>
```

With the local variable (defined with #) you get a reference of the test component itself. You can then use it to display its "x-value" property using interpolation into the input content of the test component.